# Trying to initiate UINavigationController From A Subview in UISegmentControl

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have UISegmentControl in one ViewController where i have embedded a NavigationController with it for navigation. In that UISegmentControl, i have three 3 segments where i'm switching between three UITableViewControllers. These UITableViewControllers are shown in subview while switching from one segment to another. What i want to do is when a user tap on a cell, i want to reveal DetailViewController for the same in that view.

Here's the code for switching UISegmentControl -

```
-(IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender{

 segmentControl=(UISegmentedControl*)sender;


 if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {

 firstView = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstTopViewController"];

    [self.view addSubview:firstView.view];

    NSLog(@"1");
}
}
```

In FirstTopViewController.m -

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


DetailViewController *detailView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

FirstViewController *firstView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];

detailView.detail = [self.jobsArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstView];

[self.view addSubview:nav.view];

[nav pushViewController:jobDetailView animated:YES];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

UINavigationController appears, but in the same subview as that of UITableViewController and crashes as soon i try to scroll or tap on any segment. How can i achieve the navigation properly? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the error message you get?

Comment: lldb is what i get in blue color

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it, here's what I think you need to do:

In your `valueChanged` method is where you set up the `UINavigationController` and its root viewController (firstViewController). Like so:

```
FirstViewController *firstView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstView];

[self.view addSubview:nav.view];
```

And then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` do something like this:

```
DetailViewController *detailView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView]
```

Make sense?

**Edit:** The point being, combine your navController and firstViewController at the beginning (upon segmented control value changed) and then later upon cell selection create and push the detailViewController onto the existing navController.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is, i already have UINavigationController embedded in storyboard and that's where i have UISegmentControl. I don't want the view in subview for navigation. I want it to use the same self.navigationController. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this will work/ is the best approach. It sounds like the segmented control is controlling several UIViewControllers, acting like a UITabBarController. It's best to keep the two types of UIViewController management separate (TabBarController-like hierarchy vs. push/pop linear hierarchy) by splitting them into effectively two navigation controllers, each managing a separate view hierarchy. I think what I suggest above is a better approach, unless there's something I'm not understanding about your setup.